# behaviour of mysql_store_result function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two questions for MySql C API.

a) If the result to the query is greater than the size of the ram then how does the function  `mysql_store_result` behaves. What happens in this case when we call the `mysql_fetch_row` function?

b) Is there any way by which we can parse this data structure more than once? By more than once I mean that I want to access each row two times let us suppose. I want to do this because the data I will be handling will be large in size( greater than RAM available on system ) and I don't want to create an in memory copy again for this data.

EDIT:

Here is what I am doing: I am making a bloom filter from the result of a query from database. suppose the query `i` is `select user_id from user;`. Now let us have 100 table in the database which will return set of users when above query is run against that table in the database.

Now I would like to test the membership of some table, let us assume k, in the bloom filter of first table. Now what I thought was instead of querying the database again I would like to store the result of the query `i` temporarily and use it when required.

Comment: YOu dont need to worry with the size of the main memory, because there are many ways(paging, virtual memory and so on) the OS manages it.

Comment: yeah that is what I thought. Can you tell me to achieve the behavior in the second part of the question so that I can use the result set multiple times.

Comment: I would really recommend figuring out how you can pass through the result set once if the data is larger than the client system memory.  It was likely expensive to dig up off of disk for the db, maybe doesn't fit in its query cache, and expensive to ship over a network or socket so repeating that process would be pretty expensive in addition to using an O(n^2) implementation.

Comment: elaborate ur requirement

Comment: I have edited the question and might seem that what I am doing s almost necessary but if you have a different viewpoint then please care to explain.